# How to make zsh on a mac 10.9 use python 2.7.6 instead of Apple's preinstalled 2.7.5

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

How do I make zsh on a mac use python 2.7.6 which I have in my /usr/local/bin/python instead of python 2.7.5 which is in /usr/bin/python? (without needing to type   /usr/local/bin/python before the script I want to run). My path setting on .zprofile is:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

in your `~/.zshrc` file.